# Issue in compoundjs "Adapter is not define'

Tags: node.js, mongodb, npm, compoundjs

i am new to compoundJs, developing sample application while am running the application it shows me Adapter not define. it wants to install

```
 npm install jugglingdb-mongoose
```

while am installing npm it shows

```
    'jugglingdb-mongoose' is not in the npm registry.
     npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it
```

is there is any way to install these npm.

how to fix this. can any one help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no mongoose adapter, use jugglingdb-mongodb adapter instead.